# Multiple ssh connection created while reading a file from remote server linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, remote-server

I have a requirement where I need to read latest update from a  log file from a remote server and append it to a file in existing server. I have written the below shell script

```
Shell script: getMsgpka.sh
sshpass -p '***' ssh msgpka@10.9.7.66 tail -f /home/DBG/logs/tester.DBG.log | tee -a /var/opt/data/NOTIFICATION/log/MSGPKA/tester.DBG.log
```

I have run this script using nohup as shown below

```
nohup sh /var/opt/script/getMsgpka.sh &
```

Issue is that I see multiple sessions created for various intervals.

```
[user1@knoc1 opt]$ ps -ef | grep msgpka
user1    421      1  0 04:35 ?        00:00:00 sshpass -p zzzzzzzzzzz ssh msgpka@10.9.7.66 tail -f /home/DBG/logs/tester.DBG.log
user1    423    421  0 04:35 pts/110  00:00:00 ssh msgpka@10.9.7.66 tail -f /home/DBG/logs/tester.DBG.log
user1    576      1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:00 sshpass -p zzzzzzzzzzz ssh msgpka@10.9.7.66 tail -f /home/DBG/logs/tester.DBG.log
user1    578    576  0 Mar09 pts/28   00:00:00 ssh msgpka@10.9.7.66 tail -f /home/DBG/logs/tester.DBG.log
user1   3798      1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:00 sshpass -p zzzzzzzzzzz ssh msgpka@10.9.7.66 tail -f /home/DBG/logs/tester.DBG.log
user1   3800   3798  0 Mar09 pts/46   00:00:00 ssh msgpka@10.9.7.66 tail -f /home/DBG/logs/tester.DBG.log
user1   5468      1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:00 sshpass -p zzzzzzzzzzz ssh msgpka@10.9.7.66 tail -f /home/DBG/logs/tester.DBG.log
user1   5470   5468  0 Mar09 pts/59   00:00:00 ssh msgpka@10.9.7.66 tail -f /home/DBG/logs/tester.DBG.log
user1   7543      1  0 04:45 ?        00:00:00 sshpass -p zzzzzzzzzzz ssh msgpka@10.9.7.66 tail -f /home/DBG/logs/tester.DBG.log
user1   7547   7543  0 04:45 pts/111  00:00:00 ssh msgpka@10.9.7.66 tail -f /home/DBG/logs/tester.DBG.log
user1   7686      1  0 06:35 ?        00:00:00 sshpass -p zzzzzzzzzzz ssh msgpka@10.9.7.66 tail -f /home/DBG/logs/tester.DBG.log
```

How can I solve this issue to have only one process running which fetches the data from the remote server?

Comment: The main issue is the `tail -f` that never terminates, so the SSH session is kept open.

Comment: `tail -1` will give you the last line.  Check the man page for tail to see what `-f` does.

Comment: What alternate can I use ?

Comment: @stacktesting It's not clear what your intent is; you don't check what was the latest line in the local file before running `tail` remotely. You'll probably end up with a lot of duplicate lines.